# Is SharePoint OOTB e-mail confirmation of new user alerts documented anywhere?

Tags: c#, email, sharepoint-2010, smtp

As title says, I'm developing a 'subscription' feature for a SharePoint site and need to know details of available OOTB SharePoint confirmation e-mails that will be sent to a user who has just had a new alert created.

I'd like to know about configuring the settings for these e-mails if possible.

It's quite easy for me to just use the e-mail methods I've already put in place with the SMTP I'm using but I don't want the user to receive 2 e-mails about the same thing.

Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint defines the concept of alert template. Try to ask your question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com, you will raise your chance of getting answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, since all I wanted was a point in the right direction - I'd deem your comment as an answer. Post it and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint defines the concept of alert template.

An introduction can be found [on Zeb Sadiq's blog](http://blog.zebsadiq.com/post/SharePoint-2010-custom-alert-template.aspx).

Basically you will have to create xml templates for the alerts.